# Laravel 5 dynamic form validatioin

Tags: forms, validation, laravel, dynamic, laravel-5

I have a form which has fields that can be added dynamicly. Everything works fine, but when I add some fields and submit and I make some mistake on purpose and validation fails, the dynamicly created fields disappear.

Let's say that I have 3 static fields and one dinamicly added. so it looks like that

**static fields:** keyword1, keyword2, keyword3

**dynamic fields:** keyword4

The validation error message that I get is like this:

```
The keyword0 field is required.
The keyword1 field is required.
The keyword2 field is required.
The keyword3 field is required.
```

fields 0,1,2 are in the the form with the values that I filled for them, but field 3 is not that.

How can I access this field so I can print it in my form?

**my form**

```
{!! Form::model($keywordsPlan, ['route' => ['keywordsplans.store', 'company' => $company], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal keywords-plan-form']) !!}


<div class="row">               
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        {!! Form::label('Date') !!}
        {!! Form::date('date', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>


    <table class="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Add Keyword</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">{!! Form::text(null, null, ['class' => 'form-control keyword-input']) !!}</td>
                <td scope="row"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add-keyword">Add keyword</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="table table-striped keywords-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Keyword</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($keywords as $i => $keyword)
            <tr class="keyword-row">
                <td scope="row">{!! Form::text('keyword['.$i.']', $keyword->text, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
                <td class="action"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-keyword" value="Remove"></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            <tr class="keyword-copy-row hidden">
                <td>{!! Form::text(null, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
                <td class="action"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-keyword" value="Remove"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
        {!! Form::submit('Create Plan', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg save-plan']); !!}
    </div>
</div>


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and this is my Request class for this model (form)

```
 /**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{


    $rules = [
        'date' => 'required|date|unique:keywords_plans,date',
        'approved' => 'boolean'
    ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->keyword); $i++) {

        $rules['keyword'.$i] = 'required';

    }

    return $rules;

}
```

**My controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Keyword;
use App\Company;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\KeywordsPlan;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateKeywordsPlan;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateKeywordsPlan;

class KeywordsPlanController extends Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $keywordsPlans = KeywordsPlan::all();
        return view('keywordsPlans/index', compact('keywordsPlans'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create($company)
    {
        $data['keywordsPlan'] = new KeywordsPlan;
        $data['company'] = Company::find($company);
        $data['keywords'] = $data['company']->keywords;

        return view("keywordsPlans/create", $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can detect keyword3 with `old('keyword3')` when returning from validation errors.

Comment: no that actually shows just shows null

Comment: You have to do redirect `withInput()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in Ur code at the moment.

1) The rules.

It needs to be

```
$rules['keyword.'.$i] = 'required';
```

Ur currently checking for 'keyword0'. U need to be checking for 'keyword.0'. U need a extra '.'.

Laravel's validatior uses array.index when it needs to check array['index']'s value.

U can actually just add `'keyword.*' = 'required'` into the rules array instead of the for loop there. (Available in 5.2. Not sure about previous versions.)

2) When Ur repopulating the form after errors U need to be repopulating using values from session. But Ur using $keywords regardless of wether its a fresh form or a repopulated one.

U need to do something like this

```
  @if (Input::old('keywords'))
        @foreach (Input::old('keywords') as $i => $keyword)
         <tr class="keyword-row">
                <td scope="row">{!! Form::text('keyword['.$i.']', $keyword->text, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
                <td class="action"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-keyword" value="Remove"></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
@else
         @foreach ($keywords as $i => $keyword)
            <tr class="keyword-row">
                <td scope="row">{!! Form::text('keyword['.$i.']', $keyword->text, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
                <td class="action"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-keyword" value="Remove"></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach

    @endif
```

And also for non-dynamic form values U will need to use the old helper this way.

```
{!! Form::date('date', Input::old('date'), $date, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Check these links to know more about this stuff.
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding. Note the priority order

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it seems like your validations IS working. If you receive the following errors:

```
The keyword0 field is required.
The keyword1 field is required.
The keyword2 field is required.
The keyword3 field is required.
```

This line:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->keyword); $i++) {
```

Is looping through items 0 through 3, which is a total of 4 items.  You said you have 3 static items plus 1 dynamic.  Is that not accurate?

Comment: when I try to use $this->keyword it shows me this error

Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine::$keywords (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/resources/views/keywordsPlans/create.blade.php)

Comment: It doesn't seem like your view has access to $keywords. You need to pass that keywords collection to your view from your controller. i.e view('keywordsPlans.create')->withKeywords($keywords)

Comment: I have access.... in my myController#create i have this line


$data['keywords'] = $data['company']->keywords;

return view("keywordsPlans/create", $data);

Comment: could you post your controller method as well?